# Jetpack Compose- clickable not working properly, works randomely and also sometimes triggering random events

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

On one of the Composable screen, clickables not working as expected. The screen has many clickables and most of the time click does not work on 1st click and then click behavior is completely random that sometime it works and sometime not.

Also, if I navigate away from this Composable screen on some action and then come back, sometimes any random click getting triggered.

I tried debugging it to check whether function inside clickables is called or not so I can assure that function don't have any issues. And found whenever click does not work, the function itself did not get called. This means click event itself did not get registered by the Composable.

What could be the reason?

Comment: Provide a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Abhimanyu I wish I could provide the reproducible example but the Composable working fine on other screens. Its just this particular screen which is having this issue. So I am looking for hints which can help me debug the issue further.